# Facebook API works fine for /feed, but not for /photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Following is the code that works fine if I am passing `/pageid/feed` to `facebook->api`, but when I change it to upload the image directly to my Facebook photo album, it will not work. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong in the following code:

```
// Works fine
$status = $facebook->api("/194458563914948/feed", 'post', $attachment);

// Does not work
$status = $facebook->api("/196878530339618/photos", 'post', $attachment);
```

## Full Source

```
    <?php

require 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = "332267477347";
$app_secret = "xxxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true,
 'fileUpload' => true,

));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  


$user = $facebook->getUser();
//echo $user;

if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'photo_upload,user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}");
 exit;
}
else {
$accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
echo "i am connected";
}
  $valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');


//to get the page access token to post as a page
foreach($accounts_list['data'] as $account){
      if($account['id'] == 194458563914948){      // my page id =123456789
        $access_token = $account['access_token'];
        echo "<p>Page -- Access Token: $access_token</p>";
        }
    }

//posting to the page wall

if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES))
{  
$aid = '421539304540205';
$folder = "pak/".$_FILES['pic']['name'];
$fold = 'http://snowdrop.com.pk/fb/'.$folder;
echo $fold."<br>";
if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $folder) )
{
#Upload photo here
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
$attachment = array('message' => $_POST['textfield'],
                           'aid' => $aid,
   'source' => '@' . $img,
                                'access_token' => $access_token,


                );
$status = $facebook->api("/421539304540205/photos", 'post', $attachment);

echo $status;
var_dump($status);

 }
 else{
    echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';

}
}
?>
<body>
 <!-- Form for uploading the photo -->
 <div class="main">
  <p>Select a photo to upload on Facebook Fan Page</p>
  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Select the image: <input type="file" name="pic" />
    <br />
    <label>Description
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p><input class="post_but" type="submit" value="Upload to my album" /></p>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path you are using */406221796071956/photos* is wrong and that's why it does not work.

The reason that this path is wrong, is that *406221796071956* is the id of a picture, see for yourself, the [Graph API Explorer for *406221796071956*](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=406221796071956) says:

> "type": "photo"

If you want to publish to that album then use */196878530339618/photos*, since it's the album: [Graph API Explorer for *196878530339618*](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=196878530339618)

> "type": "album"

---

## Edit

Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/#photos for adding photos to an album.

---

## 2nd Edit

According to the documentation of the [Album object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/):

> **can_upload**
>
> Determines whether the UID can upload to the album and returns true if the user owns the album, the album is not full, and
>   the app can add photos to the album

So you need the album not to be full, to be the owner of the album and have the right permissions for uploading.

Comment: i used this as per the porblem you inspected with my code but still its not working :(   
-----------------------------

  $status = $facebook->api("/196878530339618/photos", 'post', $attachment);

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does "not working" mean exactly? Do you get an error message?

Comment: All i am trying to do is i use the above script and when i click on submit then the image appears on my wall with its description and that image can be viwed in zoom on facebook fanpage cause when i used /pageid/feed then the notification does come on the wall but with very small icon image with any link behind it (it can't be viewed in zoom over there)...

Comment: no i donot get an error message here is a link of my page http://snowdrop.com.pk/fb/abc.php

Comment: Link with the replacement of ALBUMID: http://snowdrop.com.pk/fb/abc.php and this link contains the code line with /pageid/feed (which is working fine but with that small linky image problem) http://snowdrop.com.pk/fb/1.php

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say, I'm sorry. Can you try to be more clear?

Comment: When i changed the id to the respective id you told me to change from 406221796071956 to 196878530339618 ($status = $facebook->api("/196878530339618/photos", 'post', $attachment); ) in my code and test it online then it didn't work again and didnot upload any image to my wall photo's album on facebook and this is a link that contains that updated code (with the changed album id to WALL PHOTOS ALBUM ID)  snowdrop.com.pk/fb/abc.php .Kindly let me know what exactly am i doing wrong besides ID ?

Comment: Look, there's no such thing as "does not work". I can't, or better yet, won't do all of the work for you, if you want help, at least find out why it's failing. Also, don't direct me to your app cuz I won't see the php code there.

Comment: well sir i gave you the link so you can see by yourself what will happen when you click on upload to my album and my code requires an app to post images on the fanpage so if you're not login from my domain to facebook its redirected first to facebook take permission and perform the functionality accordingly i changed the album id but nothing happened same as before although it worked when i used $status = $facebook->api("/pageid/feed", 'post', $attachment);. I am not able to track any problem with my code so thats why I'm asking some pros like you to kindly help ...

Comment: you can see the most recent version of my code above (in the question section in FULL SOURCE). See if you can kindly help....

Comment: All i have tracked is that there is something wrong with this line of code only $status = $facebook->api("/196878530339618/photos", 'post', $attachment); but when i changed it to $status = $facebook->api("/pageid/feed", 'post', $attachment); it always works fine!!

Comment: There should not be anything "wrong" with that code, that is, the path itself is ok and you can check it in the [graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%2F196878530339618%2Fphotos). maybe you just don't have the permissions for the photos?

Comment: Both of these options are enabled on my page: Posting Ability: Everyone can post to Radiations3's timeline
Everyone can add photos and videos to Radiations3's timeline moreover in my application i have added for extended permissions for users as (Configure how Facebook refers users to your app) :> photo_upload , offline_access , publist_stream , manage_pages is there anything else i should add to make it work????

Comment: As it says in the [Album doc.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) you should ask for the "user_photos" permissions. And since you don't have that in your list, I assume that's the problem. Also, don't ask for "offline_access" it's deprecated and should not be used. Now, you **HAD** to get an error when asking for something that you don't have the permissions for, but you said nothing about it, are you aware of the amount of time you could have saved us both if you would just check?

Comment: I have finally tracked what exactly is the problem i guess its because   "can_upload": false, being set of my album kindly let me know how can i set it to true.....

Comment: Okay here is what i did i gave my page access token and album id to (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and checked whether my application is allowed to upload in certain album or not and it showed can_upload = true; then i am not understanding why the hell am i not able to upload images to my album. You can see my most recent code above kindly help.. I am stuck at this point only..

Comment: Issue is being resolved now there was a problem with this line of code   'source' => '@' . $img, and when i changed it to  'source' => '@' . realpath($folder), then the code worked like a charm....