# Upload image to Facebook Wall / Feed via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

I am trying to upload local images directly to a pages feed (i.e. "Wall Photos" album).

This is the code that I think *should* work:

```
<?php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $the_app_id,
    'secret' => $this_app_secret,
));
$facebook->setAccessToken($the_access_token);
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$attachment = array(
    'message' => $the_post_body,
    'name' => $this_image_name,
    'picture' => '@' . $the_absolute_path_to_image
);

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed, 'post', $attachment);
```

But this code just yields a plain text wall post with the contents of "message" (i.e. picture field is seemingly ignored). I have also tried "/page_id/feed", same result.

Now, simply changing the endpoint to "/me/photos", does upload the photo to a 'normal' album with the name of the app, but I want it to look as much like a normal post as possible and so hence into the "Wall Photos" album).

I realise that I could achieve this by querying the graph with FQL to find the object_id of the "Wall Photos" album, but if it does not exist it would require extra permissions to create it and I would rather keep permissions as simple as possible.

**If anyone could point out how to upload photos to "/me/feed" I would greatly appreciate it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this code just yields a plain text wall post with the contents of
>   "message" (i.e. picture field is seemingly ignored). I have also tried
>   "/page_id/feed", same result.

You can only give the link to picture but not the data.

> Now, simply changing the endpoint to "/me/photos", does upload the
>   photo to a 'normal' album with the name of the app, but I want it to
>   look as much like a normal post as possible and so hence into the
>   "Wall Photos" album).

Ye, it creates an album by default based on app. if already exists, it uploads to album. And generates a post.

> I realise that I could achieve this by querying the graph with FQL to
>   find the object_id of the "Wall Photos" album, but if it does not
>   exist it would require extra permissions to create it and I would
>   rather keep permissions as simple as possible.

You cannot upload to fb for me/feed end point. You should store in your server/s3/some service and give the public url to me/feed params.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - So, just to clarify, you **cannot** (i.e. not possible) upload images directly to "/*/feed"? This seems to be inconsistent with the results found by @FaizanQadri [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165264/facebook-api-works-fine-for-feed-but-not-for-photos)

Comment: Yes, its not possible. What is the inconsistent you found? He was not uploading image for /*/feed.