# Facebook RestFB publish a post/milestone along with photo to page

Tags: facebook, restfb

I am trying to post a feed on page along with photo,text posts without any error but picture doesnt get uploaded.

Also similar to Milestones it gets posted but how do i attach/upload a photo to it.

I am trying to Post a Milestone on FB using RestFB.

```
FacebookType publishResult = facebookClient.publish("pagename" + "/milestones",
                        FacebookType.class,
                        BinaryAttachment.with("photo", fileToUpload),
                        Parameter.with("title", title),
                        Parameter.with("picture", ""),
                        Parameter.with("description", description),
                        Parameter.with("start_time", new Date())
                        -......
```

But it posts the milestone without posting photo

Comment: Hey @Ash, welcome to SO.  When asking a question on SO, it is important that you include all relevant information (especially things you have tried that may not have worked) so that we can help you out to the best of our ability.  SO **is not** a group that will do your work for you.

Comment: Sorry @Enigmadan,Well details are :

Comment: updated in  the question...

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a (deliberate?) limitation of the Facebook Graph API.  See [Upload image to Facebook Wall / Feed via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897817/upload-image-to-facebook-wall-feed-via-graph-api)

You may post image data directly to a photo album but the feed endpoints only accept image URLs.